How to get response data in chrome extension
I want to get data of request and response of web request using the chrome extension.
let data = [];

// Capture the request body
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {
    if (details.url.startsWith("https://myDomain")) {
      console.log('Request details:', details);

      const requestData = {
        url: details.url,
        method: details.method,
        requestBody: details.requestBody ? new TextDecoder().decode(new Uint8Array(details.requestBody.raw[0].bytes)) : ''
      };

      data.push(requestData);
      chrome.storage.local.get({ savedData: [] }, function(result) {
        const savedData = result.savedData;
        savedData.push(requestData);
        chrome.storage.local.set({ savedData: savedData });
      });
    }
  },
  { urls: ["https://myDomain"] },
  ["requestBody"]
);


// Function to download data as CSV
function downloadCSV() {
  chrome.storage.local.get({ savedData: [] }, function(result) {
    const savedData = result.savedData;

    if (savedData.length === 0) {
      console.log('No data to download.');
      return;
    }

    const csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,"
      + ["URL,Method,RequestBody,ResponseBody"].concat(savedData.map(d =>
        `${d.requestBody}`
      ).join("\n"));

    const encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    chrome.downloads.download({
      url: encodedUri,
      filename: "data.csv",
      conflictAction: "overwrite"
    }, () => {
      // Clear data after download
      chrome.storage.local.set({ savedData: [] });
    });
  });
}

// Automatically trigger download at intervals (e.g., every 5 minutes)
setInterval(() => {
  downloadCSV();
}, 10000); // 5 minutes

// Optionally, trigger download when a specific tab is active
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(() => {
  downloadCSV();
});

Now this code help me to fetch the request data but I don't know how can get response data from the server of request.
I want to make extension that fetch the data between my browser and https://mydomin and save it in .csv file.
